# MVC 2.0 - Custom handling of all errors to return json

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, exception, custom-errors

I have an MVC 2 app that I want all requests to return json.  I have overridden a `HandleErrorAttribute` and an `AuthorizeAttribute`.  My goal is that all errors (even 403 and 404) are returned as json.

Here is my error handler.  `ExceptionModel` is a simple class defining any error returned by my application.  The Exception handler is a class that translates the error details into a formatted e-mail and sends it to me.

```
public class HandleErrorJsonAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        context.ExceptionHandled = true;

        RaiseErrorSignal(context.Exception);

        context.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        serializer.Serialize(context.HttpContext.Response.Output, new ExceptionModel(context.Exception));
    }

    private static void RaiseErrorSignal(Exception ex)
    {
        IExceptionHandler handler = Resolve();

        handler.HandleError(ex.GetBaseException());
    }

    private static IExceptionHandler Resolve()
    {
        return ServiceLocator.Locate<IExceptionHandler>();
    }
}
```

Here is the Exception model for clarification

```
public class ExceptionModel
{
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public ExceptionModel() : this(null)
    {

    }

    public ExceptionModel(Exception exception)
    {
        ErrorCode = 500;
        Message = "An unknown error ocurred";

        if (exception != null)
        {
            if (exception is HttpException)
                ErrorCode = ((HttpException)exception).GetHttpCode();

            Message = exception.Message;
        }
    }

    public ExceptionModel(int errorCode, string message)
    {
        ErrorCode = errorCode;
        Message = message;
    }
}
```

and finally, my custom authorize attribute.  I an using forms auth, but I did not want any of the automatic redirection.  I simply want the error to show on the screen and stop any further processing.

```
public class AuthorizeTokenAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public bool SuperAdminOnly { get; set; }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        bool authorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);

        if(!SuperAdminOnly)
            return authorized;

        if(!authorized)
            return authorized;

        return SessionHelper.UserIsSuperAdmin(httpContext.User.Identity.Name);
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        throw new HttpException(403, "Access Denied");
    }
}
```

This all works great for most errors, but it is missing one thing.  I have a controller action like this.

```
[AuthorizeToken]
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult MyAction()
{
    return new JsonResult();
}
```

It works fine when you submit via post, but on a get I receive an unhandled 404 error.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource
>   you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed,
>   had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please
>   review the following URL and make sure
>   that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /MyController/MyAction
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET
>   Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET
>   Version:4.0.30319.1

This happens on a GET, which is to be expected as default behavior.  However, how can I handle for this condition so that I could instead return json like this

```
{"ErrorCode":404,"Message":"Page Not Found"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle errors personally I prefer the `Application_Error` event in Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var exception = Server.GetLastError();
    Response.Clear();
    Server.ClearError();

    var httpException = exception as HttpException;
    var routeData = new RouteData();
    routeData.Values["controller"] = "Errors";
    routeData.Values["action"] = "Index";
    routeData.Values["error"] = exception;

    IController errorController = new ErrorsController();
    errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
}
```

and then have an ErrorsController:

```
public class ErrorsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(Exception exception)
    {
        var errorCode = 500;
        var httpException = exception as HttpException;
        if (httpException != null)
        {
            errorCode = httpException.ErrorCode;
        }

        return Json(new
        {
            ErrorCode = errorCode,
            Message = exception.Message
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```